# switching templates dynamically in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, dynamic, themes, add-filter

Right now I'm trying to switch the template that Wordpress uses depending on the device that is viewing the site.

The exact issue here is that the ONLY thing that seems to be switching are the scripts and stylesheets. The actual templates them selves (index, header, footer) stay the same.

Here is the function I'm using to do this:

```
<?
  function fxn_change_theme($device) {
    $header = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_UA_DEVICE'];
    if ($header === 'mobile') {
        $theme = 'jankness-mobile';
    } elseif ($header === 'tablet') {
        $theme = 'jankness-tablet';
    } else {
        $theme = 'jankness-desktop';
    }
    return $theme;
  }
  add_filter('template', 'fxn_change_theme');
  add_filter('option_template', 'fxn_change_theme');
  add_filter('option_stylesheet', 'fxn_change_theme');
?>
```

Also, the only filter that's doing anything seems to be 'template', the option filters don't do much. I've tried looking up what they do and it's not clear to me at the moment.

What might be the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, since the code I was using was sitting in functions.php it was not able to manipulate the theme content earlier enough in the Wordpress core process. So the solution was to move the code into a very simple plugin exactly as it is, and hook in to the theme_setup point using the same code I used here.